# How to edit text with a keyboard on the lauch of an application

Tags: iphone, keyboard, textfield, edit, launch

I've got a textfield within my View. How can I be able to force the user to type within this textField on Launch. So push the keyboard in the View on Launch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In viewDidload or viewWillAppear

```
[yourtextField becomefirstresponder];
```

Comment: Thank you, however i needed to watch the syntax [MyTextField becomeFirstResponder];

Answer (score 1):

in ViewDidload or ViewWillAppear method add

```
[urTextField becomefirstresponder]
```